# Not Updating Group Policy Changes

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-7, group-policy

I have been working on updating my companies group policies and I have run into a problem with the user policy not applying correctly.

Previously the old policy had a folder redirect for the desktop and the start menu. The folders resided on a server.

In the new policy we have removed this and changes the folders to reside on the local computer.

It seems that the policy isn't being properly applied because it is behaving like the old policy is still in play.

If I delete the local profile that is created on the local computer and then allow the profile to be recreated everything works correctly.

Is there anyway to "flush" out the old user policy settings being applied and just have the server reapply all of the settings? I would like be able to deploy a fix to the masses vs having to hand touch every computer.

Please note I have done gpupdate /force several time on multiple machine and I get the same result.

Comment: Did you just remove the old policy, or create a new one?

Comment: I had created a new set of policies that we had already tested. So when i applied the new ones i unlinked the old one.

Comment: AFAIK, this is still valid for Folder Redirection. You can't simply remove the GPO that originally configured Folder Redirection nor can you simply replace it with a new one. - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/888203